# Magento 2.1- How to Integrate Google Maps API in Ui Component Form

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, google-map

I have been looking around to find any good solution, that could help me to integrate **Google Map** to my admin form, my goal was to get the latitude, longitude and zoom from the drag able marker on the map to dynamically fill my form fields.

Is it necessary to attach the `JS` in Knockout format?
Did any body achieve this?

Comment: did u manage to find how ?

Comment: @Zorox yes I did

Comment: share please :)